# Installing ngx-bootstrap for ASP.NET Core 2.0 & webpack (Angular 4.2.5)

Tags: angular, webpack, asp.net-core, ngx-bootstrap

I try to use ngx-bootstrap in an ASP.NET Core 2.0 project, with aspnet-prerendering and webpack. There's no info about this config in the [getting started page](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/getting-started#getting-started) of the docs.

Could anybody direct me to a guide or help me how to integrate this package into the following configuration?

I tried to add the latest version, but it started complaining about incompatible package versions. When I changed the package.json according to the error messages, then my existing code broke.

What I want to achieve is to keep the current configuration (angular, etc.)  and use the bootstrap package.

My project.json looks like this:

```
    "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/http": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "4.2.5",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0",
    "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "chai": "4.0.2",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3",
    "preboot": "4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "2.4.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ngx-cookie": "^2.0.1"
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: Didn't wrote such docs yet

Comment: Hi @valorkin, thx for the answer. Could you please let me know if my environment is supported and if yes, what is the correct way to make it load and work? I tried it many ways and the result is always some kind of "No Provider" error. I guess I do s.g. wrong, but would be much easier to overcome if we had a guide. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I managed to work it out. For anybody who is interested, I have published a [sample repository on GitHub](https://github.com/csegyud/ASPNETCore_ngx-bootstrap_Sample).

@valorkin, if you wish, you can freely grab this sample as an ASP.NET core guide in your beautiful project. :)

---

*In a nut shell, here is the point:*

**ngx-bootstrap installation steps:**

This is all about the client app only, and has pretty nothing to do with the ASP.Net Core project. The only difference compared to a stock angular-cli generated project is that it has a little different folder structure and file naming.

E.g. the *package.json* file is in the root folder of the ASP.NET project, not in the angular app’s root, or the Visual Studio approach does not have an *src* folder under the *ClientApp* structure. The *app.module* file is also split into chunks to manage shared code in *app.shared.module.ts*, browser specific code in *app.module.browser.ts*, while server specific code in *app.module.server.ts* file. Etc.

1. Fire up **Visual Studio 2017** and create a new project from the **ASP.Net Core Web Application** template. In the template options select Angular.
2. Add ngx-bootstrap to **package.json**, which is in the project root's folder. (To learn more about npm packages and package.json file, [check the npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json).)
   If the bootstrap package is not included yet (but it is in this template), add that too, because it is prerequisite. 
   Since this project template contains webpack integration out of the box, it will find our newly added packages automatically, and so we do not need to modify the webpack config file to include them. This is just cool.

   ```
   "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
   "ngx-bootstrap": "2.0.0-rc.0",
   "css": "2.2.1",
   ```
3. Import whichever modules you want to use in app.module.shared.ts (~\ClientApp\app\components\ **app.module.shared.ts**).

   ```
   // Load as many modules as you want to use. 
   // For demonstration purposes, I load AlertModule only.
   import {
           AlertModule, 
       //AccordionModule,
       //ButtonsModule,
       //CarouselModule,
       //CollapseModule,
       //BsDatepickerModule,
       //BsDropdownModule,
       //ModalModule,
       //PaginationModule,
       //ProgressbarModule,
       //SortableModule,
       //TabsModule,
       //TimepickerModule,
       //TooltipModule,
       //TypeaheadModule
   } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
   ```
4. In the same file, add the above imported modules to the **@NgModule's imports** collection by calling their forRoot() function:.

   ```
   imports: [
       CommonModule,
       HttpModule,
       FormsModule,

       // Bootstrap ----------------------------
           AlertModule.forRoot(),
       //AccordionModule.forRoot(),
       //ButtonsModule.forRoot(),
       //...
       //TooltipModule.forRoot()
       //---------------------------------------

       //...

       RouterModule.forRoot([
           { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
           { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
           { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
           { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
           { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
   ])
   ```
5. Start using them in Components. 
   E.g. add an **<alert>** tag in the home component template under ~\ClientApp\app\components\home\ **home.component.html** file.

***Note*** that you do not need to import Bootstrap modules in your component ts file!

```
    <alert type="success" dismissible="true"><br />
        <b>Congratulations</b><br />, ngx-bootstrap package was loaded successfully. This alert is shown by the package. Great!<br />
        Now click the <b>[x]</b> button on right side to close this alert.
    </alert>
```

Comment: awesome! you actually can add link to your answer in our readme, so ppl could find it ;)